# Changing a 3-phase motor for a single phase motor

Tags: three-phase, single-phase

My work is getting rid of their commercial power washer. It has a 5 hp, 1750 RPM, 3-phase motor on it. Can I just buy a 5 hp 1750 RPM single-phase motor and swap it out and everything will work?

Edit: I have 220 volt ran to run my air compressor and welder.

Comment: Is your question, can I plug a single phase motor in a 3 phase driver. I'm not an expert, but I doubt that the wiring, the drives,  the safeties and everything else will handle the extra current and remain safe.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option will be to keep the existing 3 phase motor, and get a single phase to 3 phase VFD. You may need a VFD with higher VA rating - perhaps 5 kVA (7.5 HP). [Automation Direct](https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/shopping/catalog/drives_-a-_soft_starters/ac_variable_frequency_drives_(vfd)/general_purpose_vfds#Horsepower_By_Input_Phase_ms=(%20%225hp%201-phase%22%20%227-1/2hp%201-phase%22)&start=0) sells 5 HP and 7.5 HP devices for about $500-$600. [Their 5 HP single phase motor](https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/shopping/catalog/motors/ac_motors/conveyor-z-farm_duty/mtf2-005-1b18) is $926.

Answer (score 0):

Finding a single phase 5 horse motor will not be easy .Three phase motors are more efficient and lighter .If you find such a single phase  motor it may not fit .Remember that you will need single phase of say 5 Kw to make 5Hp when power factor and losses are taken into account. Do not even try to plug this into a regular wall socket ,it will overload popping fuses.You could consider using a motor drive but you still need lots of single phase.

Comment: I apologize im not super smart on electrical like this. I have 220v ran for my compressor and welder. Ive found several 5hp 1750rpm motors that are single phase online. I just wanted to double check that it would work before ordering it.